# difference between devel folder and install folder in catkin_ws

Tags: ros, devel, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When catkin_make is used , devel folder is generated along with some setup files . However, when catkin_make install is used , a new folder install is generated along with the setup files . How are these two folders different in terms of the files they contain ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253363/difference-between-devel-folder-and-install-folder-in-catkin_ws/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if [wiki/catkin - workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces) answers your questions.

---

Edit:

> I also wanted to know the difference in terms of sourcing the setup files in both these folders . How can i know when to source the files from devel space and when from install space

From the page I linked to:

> Once targets are built, they can be installed into the [install space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Install_Space) by invoking the install target, usually with `make install`

If all packages in your source space have the required `install(..)` directives in their `CMakeLists.txt`, then there should be no difference between the `devel` and the `install` space, when *running* nodes from those packages.

For normal development though, I'd always just use the `devel` space (name sort of implies that). The `install` space is typically an 'end-station': you use it for deployment.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-02-01**:
That partly clarified the question.Thank you . I also wanted to know the difference in terms of sourcing the setup files in both these folders . How can i know when to source the files from devel space and when from install space

**Comment by [baselink](https://answers.ros.org/users/105721/baselink/) on 2022-05-23**:
If I do not run the 'make install' command, I can roslaunch the package. Right?
Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-23**:
`make install` is not a command you should use with ROS packages.

**Comment by [baselink](https://answers.ros.org/users/105721/baselink/) on 2022-05-23**:
Yes, I think so. Thanks.